# Find projects targeting .net framework x in a solution - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-reflector

I was wondering if anybody knows of a way to easily find all projects targeting a specific runtime framework (I.e. 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 etc) within a Visual Studio 2010 solution.

I'm working with a solution with hundreds of projects (all targeting 3.5) that was recently converted from VS 2008 to VS 2010 and is now facing a couple of indirect dependency issues which I need to resolve. Having to open each project and looking at the project's properties is not really an option for me.

Something clearly went wrong when the projects were converted to VS 2010. Using .NET Reflector shows that some of the references in the DLLs have references to mscorlib, System, System.Xml, System.Configuration, System.Data.SqlXml, System.Security all Version 4.0.0.0 but looking at the project itself there are no references to any 4.0 assemblies.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a nice Visual Studio 2010 extension which does exactly what I needed.

Have a look at VSCommands 2010, direct [link](http://vscommands.com/features/#SolutionProperties)...

Hope this will help anybody else facing a similar issue in the future.